# href not working on navbar-toggle - bootstrap

Tags: css, html, tags, bootstrap-4

I fail to understand why `href` is not working on `button` tag for `navbar-toggler`.When I press the cart tab, i should be routed to the cart.php view.
This is my code:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="cart.php" href="cart.php"  aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false"  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <i class="icono-navbar icon-shopping-cart"></i>
</button>
```

[this is my nav-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFY88.png)

Answer (score 1):

href is not a valid attribute for a button so that will not work

However, you can style an anchor to look like a button or use JavaScript to do the navigation.

Comment: Thanks. I solved putting `a` tag instead a `button` and adding this `role="button"`, like this:
        <a class="navbar-toggler" role="button" href="cart.php" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false"  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="icono-navbar icon-shopping-cart"></i>
        </a>